# Tabbing User Control In Listbox DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I have a User Control in a ListBox and when I use the tab key to focus I'd like to get the focus on the TextBox in my Control instead of the Custom Control. How can I do it?

I simplified the code because In my control I have other UI Elements.

User Control Code:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="txtFreeTextDescription" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyleLargeDynamic}" Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
</Grid>
```

ListBox Code:

```
<ListBox Name="lsbItems" DataContext="{Binding}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <local:SectionDynamicItem x:Name="ucSectionDynamicItem" Description="{Binding SectionItem.Description}"  />
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me....

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}"
            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5" Focusable="False">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks       <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/> did the trick just fine!

Answer (score -1):

Check below link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/98d8423c-9719-4291-94e2-c5bf3d80cd46/

Thanks
Rajnikant